# PowerShell : retrieve file from GitHub

Tags: powershell, github, powershell-3.0

I need to download a file from my GitHub private repo.  So following the instructions on the GitHub site, I created an OAuth token for my credentials.

Then I executed this PS script :

```
$WebClient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Headers.Add('Authorization','{OAuth token}')
$uri = "https://github.com/mycompany/myrepo/blob/master/myfile.zip"
$targetPath = "c:\temp"
$WebClient.DownloadFile($uri, $targetPath)
```

However, `$WebClient.DownloadFile()` returns a 404.  This is strange because I can retrieve the file from `$uri` via a browser logged-in to GitHub with same credentials used to create OAuth token.

Comment: See this site for a my current solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951561/use-invoke-webrequest-with-a-username-and-password-for-basic-authentication-on-t

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://help.github.com/articles/downloading-files-from-the-command-line) your two options are HTTPS basic auth and an OAuth token.

So to add basic auth to your webclient try this:

```
$url = 'https://github.com/mycompany/myrepo/blob/master/myscript.ps1'
$wc = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.NetworkCredential 'username', 'password'
iex ($wc.DownloadString($url))
```

To use OAuth you'll need to add a header named `Authorization` and provide the token string as an argument. Replace the NetworkCredential line from the example above with this.

```
$wc.Headers.Add('Authorization','token your_token')
```

Follow the instructions [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-oauth-token-for-command-line-use) to create the OAuth token using [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html). This part can be done with PowerShell but it's only a one time thing so you can just use the example GitHub provides.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I've amended my question to be more clear: I just meant https as a shorthand for an authenticated site to which credentials must be supplied. And yes I need OAuth as I can't commit plain-text credentials to source-control.

Comment: I've added some additional instructions. I do not have a private repo to test against however.

Comment: I configure WebClient Authorization header with OAuth token, but on attempting file-download I get 404. Please see my amended question.

Comment: BaltoStar: This seems to be the only post I can find here on StackOverflow on this subject. Don't suppose there have any revelations in the last five months?

Comment: This solution does not work by the way. Not sure why it is marked as the answer.

Comment: Also you can use the `WebClient.DownloadFile(url, path)` signature