# Use Invoke-WebRequest with a username and password for basic authentication on the GitHub API

Tags: powershell, github-api, basic-authentication

With cURL, we can pass a username with an HTTP web request as follows:

```
$ curl -u <your_username> https://api.github.com/user
```

The `-u` flag accepts a username for authentication, and then cURL will request the password. The cURL example is for [Basic authentication with the GitHub Api](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/).

How do we similarly pass a username and password along with Invoke-WebRequest? The ultimate goal is to user PowerShell with Basic authentication in the GitHub API.

Comment: $pair should be `$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"` Check the approved answer. I was using the above and it gave me too much pain

Comment: None of the solutions that suggest the `-Credential` approach work as the correct auth header is not generated when the request is made.

Comment: @Shaun Luttin - This is a question..... and answer site, not a Question Answer site. This one user would prefer to see a succinct as possible question and answers other than what worked for your particular situation, but not having to read that twice (once in the edited Question, now come QuestionAnswer, and then again in answers). If the concern was the answer that helped you would not be closest to the question, StackExchange has functionality to bring the best/accepted answer to as close as possible to question already.

Comment: @user66001 Thank you for the feedback. I have moved my answer-in-question to its own answer for later reference. I think this is an improvement.

Comment: In `curl` I have to use the parameter `--anyauth` in order to work with user/password. Otherwise I get a permission error.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

I am assuming Basic authentication here.

```powershell
$cred = Get-Credential
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://whatever' -Credential $cred
```

You can get your credential through other means (`Import-Clixml`, etc.), but it does have to be a `[PSCredential]` object.

### Edit based on comments:

GitHub is breaking RFC as they explain in the [link you provided](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/):

> The API supports Basic Authentication as defined in RFC2617 with a few
>   slight differences. The main difference is that the RFC requires
>   unauthenticated requests to be answered with 401 Unauthorized
>   responses. In many places, this would disclose the existence of user
>   data. Instead, the GitHub API responds with 404 Not Found. This may
>   cause problems for HTTP libraries that assume a 401 Unauthorized
>   response. The solution is to manually craft the Authorization header.

Powershell's `Invoke-WebRequest` does to my knowledge wait for a 401 response before sending the credentials, and since GitHub never provides one, your credentials will never be sent.

## Manually build the headers

Instead you'll have to create the basic auth headers yourself.

Basic authentication takes a string that consists of the username and password separated by a colon `user:pass` and then sends the Base64 encoded result of that.

Code like this should work:

```powershell
$user = 'user'
$pass = 'pass'

$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"

$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))

$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"

$Headers = @{
    Authorization = $basicAuthValue
}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://whatever' -Headers $Headers
```

You could combine some of the string concatenation but I wanted to break it out to make it clearer.

Comment: As I said it works for Basic authentication, but I don't know what kind of authentication the GitHub API uses. You could post some details about what's expected and that might help us solve the issue.

Comment: The GitHub Api uses basic authentication as follows: https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/

Comment: Ah, it seems GitHub is (by their own admission) not following RFC, but Powershell is. I've edited the answer with more information and a workaround.

Comment: Good for you for perusing the RFC. I admire that.

Comment: It works. I'm surprise by how verbose this is compared to cURL.

Comment: Yeah, if you're going to be doing a lot of these kinds of calls, I'd recommend wrapping this in a function. As I said I really broke out all the pieces for clarity, but you *could* do it all on one line (it would just be messy).

Comment: I am trying to download a file using PowerShell with Invoke-WebRequest command. I tried your method to perform basic auth however I got this error:  the term '<my user name>' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.

Comment: @Aref, you should post a new question with the code you're using. If you do so and let me know about I'll take a look.

Comment: You'll need to manually build the headers if trying to authentication against the Visual Studio Team Services REST API too

Comment: It seems that the Bitbucket API version 2.0 also needs a manually created Authorization header.

Comment: I love how people complain that powershell is so much harder than BASH, but in reality there's things like this that are just plain cleaner because of the Object Oriented style over string manipulation

Answer (score 68):

Use this:

```
$root = 'REST_SERVICE_URL'
$user = "user"
$pass= "password"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user, $secpasswd)

$result = Invoke-RestMethod $root -Credential $credential
```

Comment: For some reason the selected answer didn't work for me when using it on TFS vNext, but this one did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The selected answer did not work for running a powershell runbook on azure to initiate a triggered job but this answer did work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. No headers get added according to Fiddler.

Comment: I can confirm that this method works well on PowerShell Core 7.3.2 on macOS.

Answer (score 39):

If someone would need a one liner:

```
iwr -Uri 'https://api.github.com/user' -Headers @{ Authorization = "Basic "+ [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("user:pass")) }
```

Answer (score 11):

`Invoke-WebRequest` follows the RFC2617 as @briantist noted, however there are some systems (e.g. JFrog Artifactory) that allow anonymous usage if the `Authorization` header is absent, but will respond with `401 Forbidden` if the header contains invalid credentials.

This can be used to trigger the `401 Forbidden` response and get `-Credentials` to work.

```
$login = Get-Credential -Message "Enter Credentials for Artifactory"

                              #Basic foo:bar
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic Zm9vOmJhcg==" }  

Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $login -Headers $headers -Uri "..."
```

This will send the invalid header the first time, which will be replaced with the valid credentials in the second request since `-Credentials` overrides the `Authorization` header.

Tested with Powershell 5.1

Comment: Is the basic authorization header necessary if you use `credential` where user and password is given? According to your answer, `-credential` will only work if it gets a `401` from `headers` before and therefore there must be `basic foo:bar` so that it is not anonymous ?

Comment: Yes, as I've written in my answer if mixed access is allowed you need to add a invalid credentials to the `Authorization` header trigger the `401` to then get `-Credential` to work.

Comment: So if `foo:bar` is correct, I need to manipulate it to .e.g. `foobar:bar` for the `auth header key`..

Comment: Sure, if someone picked the very secure user and password of `foo:bar`, then you need to use something different.

Answer (score 10):

I had to do this to get it to work:

```
$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"
$encodedCredentials = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($Pair))
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic $encodedCredentials" }
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $headers -OutFile Config.html
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way using WebRequest, I hope it will work for you

```
$user = 'whatever'
$pass = 'whatever'
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user, $secpasswd)
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic Zm9vOmJhcg==" }  
Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $credential -Headers $headers -Uri "https://dc01.test.local/"
```

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering, the `-Headers` parameter expects a dictionary or hashtable of `[string],[string]`. You can actually just define an array - e.g. `@(Authorization = 'Basic ...')` like he did here an powershell will cast it for you

Comment: @KellenStuart do not mix `basic` with `digest` which is used in the answer with the `credential` parameter.

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for our particular situation.

Notes are from [Wikipedia on Basic Auth from the Client Side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side). Thank you to [@briantist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27951845/1108891) for the help!

Combine the username and password into a single string `username:password`

```
$user = "shaunluttin"
$pass = "super-strong-alpha-numeric-symbolic-long-password"
$pair = "${user}:${pass}"
```

Encode the string to the RFC2045-MIME variant of Base64, except not limited to 76 char/line.

```
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair)
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
```

Create the Auth value as the method, a space, and then the encoded pair `Method Base64String`

```
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $base64"
```

Create the header `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==`

```
$headers = @{ Authorization = $basicAuthValue }
```

Invoke the web-request

```
Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://api.github.com/user" -Headers $headers
```

The PowerShell version of this is more verbose than the cURL version is. Why is that? @briantist pointed out that GitHub is breaking the RFC and PowerShell is sticking to it. Does that mean that cURL is also breaking with the standard?

Answer (score 3):

another way is to use certutil.exe
save your username and password in a file e.g. in.txt as username:password

```
certutil -encode in.txt out.txt
```

Now you should be able to use auth value from out.txt

```
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic $((get-content out.txt)[1])" }
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://whatever' -Headers $Headers
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a little off the OPs original request but I came across this while looking for a way to use Invoke-WebRequest against a site requiring basic authentication.

The difference is, I did not want to record the password in the script.  Instead, I wanted to prompt the script runner for credentials for the site.

Here's how I handled it

```
$creds = Get-Credential

$basicCreds = [pscredential]::new($Creds.UserName,$Creds.Password)

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -Credential $basicCreds
```

The result is the script runner is prompted with a login dialog for the U/P then, Invoke-WebRequest is able to access the site with those credentials.  This works because $Creds.Password is already an encrypted string.

I hope this helps someone looking for a similar solution to the above question but without saving the username or PW in the script

Comment: I can confirm that this method works well within PowerShell 7.3.2 on macOS.