# How to Create Public Link for Uploaded file on OwnCloud

Tags: powershell, owncloud

I created a powershell script to upload file on owncloud. Upload works fine but How do I get public Link for that uploaded file.

Below is script

```
$user = "admin"
$pass= "admin"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user, $secpasswd)
$body = "file=$(get-content c:\myupload.zip -raw)"
$targetname = "myupload.zip"
$oc = "http://myowncloud:8085/remote.php/webdav/NOC/"
Invoke-RestMethod -uri $oc$targetname -method Put -body $body -Credential $credential
```

I need to print link from the code like

```
http://myowncloud:8085/index.php/s/aTQr8JNxEYCw1Vz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that ownCloud does not create a public link for the files you upload unless you explicitly do so. In order to do this, you need to use the [ocs Share API](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.0/developer_manual/core/ocs-share-api.html#create-a-new-share). In the docs, you'll find that for public link share (i.e. `shareType = 3`) you have to perform a separate `POST` request with the `path` of the file itself.

I've slightly adapted your code to make it work with newer instances of ownCloud (version 9 et seq. [come with a different WebDAV endpoint](https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/4007)) and also to allow better URL compositions:

```
# Upload the file
$body = $(get-content c:\test.txt -raw)
$targetname = "test.txt"
$oc = "http://demo.owncloud.com/"
$dav_endpoint = "remote.php/dav/files/admin/"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $oc$dav_endpoint$targetname -Method Put -Body $body -Credential $credential

# Create a public share for that file:
$headers = @{"Ocs-APIREQUEST"="true"}
$sharing_api = "ocs/v1.php/apps/files_sharing/api/v1/shares?format=json"

# Required parameters to create the share:
$body = @{
    path = "/$($targetname)"
    shareType = "3"
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $oc$sharing_api -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body -Credential $credential
# Print the public link URL:
echo $response.ocs.data.url
```

Also take into account that this only covers the *happy path* and your script would be more correct & complete if you check for HTTP statuses on each request, the bodies of the replies...

Comment: Upload and create a public share part working fine, however it doesn't print public link URL.

Comment: @JaydeepChaudhari woop, typo; sorry. Try again with `$response.ocs.data.url`

Comment: Just for Information to above solution work, you need to Allow option for `Allow Public Uploads` and  Disable option for `Enforce Password Protection` from owncloud - settings - sharing menu.

Comment: Passing the credentials for the second Invoke-RestMethod call did not work for me, I got error code 997 (unauthorized). I needed to set the authentication header manually as described at https://stackoverflow.com/q/27951561/5525302.

Answer (score 0):

A small sidenote. If you use Nextcloud instead of OwnCloud then this works exactly the same but you have a few more options when creating the sharing links. The documentation is here: https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/12/developer_manual/core/ocs-share-api.html  Nextcloud is fully open source and faster then Owncloud.