# CURL script on Powershell to get a Response from HTTPS URL and also want to feed Username/Password

Tags: powershell, curl, https, single-sign-on, getresponse

I am new to CURL and facing problems while writing a script to get a response from HTTPS URL.

Its failing at *singleSignOn*.

**Basic command I am using is:**

```
curl -UseBasicParsing https://abc.xyz.com.au -UseDefaultCredentials
```

Can someone please help with pointers how to force SSO on CURL while doing a check on HTTPS URL?

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell `Curl` is really an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`.

If you're new to this commandlet, start easy. Try using it with Google:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.google.com'
```

Authentication is a little tricker. If the site uses basic authentication, you can use something like the following:

```
$credential= Get-Credential
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://foo.com' -Credential $credential
```

Depending on the application, you might have to construct the basic authentication headers yourself. There is a nice explanation of that in the post [Use Invoke-WebRequest with a username and password for basic authentication on the GitHub API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951561/use-invoke-webrequest-with-a-username-and-password-for-basic-authentication-on-t)

If the single-sign-on piece is using redirection, that's a different animal. You can use the Headers property on the response object to find the URL you're being redirected to. Jim McNatt has a nice [article](https://www.jmcnatt.net/quick-tips/powershell-capturing-a-redirected-url-from-a-web-request/) talking about that.