# Fetch and store JWT with Powershell

Tags: rest, api, powershell, jwt, token

I am fetching a JWT for authentication using REST calls. I am new to scripting but I manage to get the token with:

```
$params = @{"@type"="login";
 "username"="username";
 "password"="password"; 
}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://[SERVER]:[PORT]/api/jwt/login -Method POST -Body $params
```

But how can I save the Content of the response which contains the token to a parameter which I later on can use in the header for later call?

Br,
Patrik

Comment: You can save the content just like in any other programming and scripting language : by sticking it in a variabl (just like you did with the variable $params)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to save the response:

```
$res = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://[SERVER]:[PORT]/api/jwt/login -Method POST -Body $params
```

Then you can check what the response contains by typing `$res`. Your access token will probably be accessible by something like:

```
($res.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token
```

`$res.Content` takes the actual content from the response you get. Then you might want to convert it (usually from JSON as in the example) and access the specific property using `.property_name`.

As an alternative, you can try to use [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6) which gives you content as object (keep in mind that it might behave differently [depending how the service handles authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27951845/9902555)).

Comment: Thank you! Looks like you are on to something here.

Now I get

ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON-primitiv: eyJhbGci0i...(token).............
AT C:\getJWT.ps1:13 char 22
+ ($response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

+CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json9, ArgumentException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonComman

Comment: That's why I wrote `something like` before the actual code. I have no idea what's the structure of the response you get. If you want me to have a look you must post structure of `$res.Content` in your **question** (not in the comment)