# how to authenticate Invoke-RestMethod to list artifactory repositories

Tags: powershell, artifactory, credentials

Trying to get a list of Repositories from an Artifactory Enterprise v6 instance, using PowerShell 5.1 Invoke-RestMethod from Win10 desktop, but cannot see to get it to authenticate.

Seems simple enough, but this

```
$myCred = Get-Credential notStanley
$lstART = Invoke-RestMethod -URI https://<myserver>/artifactory/api/repositories -Credential $myCred
```

only returns the items that allow Anonymous access.

If I open a browser and logon to that Artifactory instance, I can then paste the above URI and get the full list of all repositories my account has access to.

Any hints what the `$myCred` is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried in the past with artifactory and `-Credential` doesnt really worked for me.

I tried the API way which is much simpler and easier to use.

**Connecting to Artifactory with API Key**

[Read here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Updating+Your+Profile) to find out how you can get the API key for your account on artifactory.

```
$header = @{"X-JFrog-Art-Api" = "yourAPIKey"}
Invoke-RestMethod -URI https://<myserver>/artifactory/api/repositories -Headers $header
```

**Using Basic Auth and -Credential**

If you do want to work with the Get-Credential prompt, make sure you use the username that works in Artifactory. Its not the same as the domain\user. [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48343686/1390548)

```
$login = Get-Credential -Message "Enter Credentials for Artifactory"

#invalid creds.. but its ok. Need to tell invoke-restmethod to use Basic Auth.
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic Zm9vOmJhcg==" }  

# use -Credential to override the credentials.
$new = Invoke-RestMethod -URI https://<server>/artifactory/api/repositories -Headers $headers -Credential $login
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Jawad.  That got me working with the API (my first try was not formed quite properly).  Following your links found a couple other questions (27951561 and 60325084) that helped me get Credential as well.  I have gone with Credential to avoid futzing with obfuscating an API Key in the source code.

My base skeleton now looks like:

```
# get standard PowerShell credential
$myCred  = Get-Credential -Message "just <name> for this server, not '<domain>\<name>'"

# format credential for Artifactory API
$credUser    = $myCred.UserName                                   # extract user name
$credPswd    = $myCred.GetNetworkCredential().password            # extract user password
$credPair    = "${credUser}:${credPswd}"                          # concatenate into BasicAuth format
$credBytes   = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($credPair)  # convert byte values to text
$cred64      = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($credBytes)       # condense a bit more secure string RFC2045-MIME    
$credAuth    = "Basic $cred64"                                    # intermediate formatting 
$restHeaders = @{ Authorization = $credAuth }                     # initialize web headers

# clear collection array
$cfgSite = @()

# locate server
$lstURL "https://<myserver>/artifactory/api/repositories"

# get list of repositories
$theseRepo = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $restHeaders -Uri $lstURL 

# collect each configuration
ForEach ($thisRepo in $theseRepo)
   {
   $thisURI  = $lstURL + $thisRepo.key
   $thisCfg  = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $restHeaders -Uri $thisURI    
   $thisCfg  | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SITE" -NotePropertyValue "$thisSite"     
   $cfgSite += $thisCfg
   }

# output to file
$cfgAll | Export-Csv .\lstArtRepoConf.csv -NoTypeInformation
```