# PowerShell: Loading Data Behind a .htaccess and .htpasswd

Tags: powershell, http, passwords

I have the problem that I can't load any data or view the content that's behind a .htpasswd. Is there a way to do this? I want to do it with PowerShell.

Here's what I have as code:

```
$username = 'test'
$password = 'test'

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://url' -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $username + $base64AuthInfo)}

$response
```

Comment: Use a network sniffer and compare your attempt with a working attempt you make manually using a browser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27951561/1427878 has some several approaches to providing the credentials.

Comment: Also, verify that you actually need just Basic auth - and not perhaps Digest. _"behind a .htaccess and .htpasswd"_ doesn't necessarily have to mean it's the former.