Downloading JSON file using Invoke-WebRequest by passing credentials and SessionToken
I am trying to download a JSON file from a URL which requires UserName, Password, User ID and SessionToken. I am referring an article: https://support.tidepool.org/hc/en-us/articles/360029368992-Downloading-your-Tidepool-Web-Notes
PS C:\Users\rajiv\OneDrive\Documents\Personal\Diabetes> Get-Credential | Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://api.tidepool.org/auth/login -Method Post

I am getting the below error. I am pretty sure that I am passing the correct credentials:
cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Credential
Invoke-WebRequest : {"code":400,"reason":"Missing id and/or password"}
At line:1 char:18
+ ... redential | Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://api.tidepool.org/auth/logi ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Thanks in advance.

One problem with this command is that the Credential parameter of Invoke-WebRequest cannot take its input from the pipeline. So you should try something like $Cred = Get-Credential;Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $Cred -Uri ...

Tried this too...didnt work

I am not sure if this will work at all because Invoke-WebRequest works differently that Curl when it comes to authentication. Username, Password, SessionToken etc. have to be part of the header. So I wouldn't use the Credential parameter at all since its the wrong parameter. You have to build a header as a hashtable with password, username etc. and provide it through the Headers parameter.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951561/use-invoke-webrequest-with-a-username-and-password-for-basic-authentication-on-t

You need to pass the credential object to Invoke-WebRequest's -Credential parameter:
$credentials = Get-Credential

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://api.tidepool.org/auth/login -Method Post -Credential $credentials

Once you've received a response, grab the session token from the response header, and the user id from the json document in the response body:
$tokenHeader = @{
  'x-tidepool-session-token' = $response.Headers['x-tidepool-session-token']
}

$userId = ($response.Content |ConvertFrom-Json).userid

Then pass the new $tokenHeader dictionary to -Headers on subsequent requests:
$notesResponse = Invoke-WebRequest "https://api.tidepool.org/message/notes/$userId" -ContentType application/json -Headers $tokenHeader

